# is solr can start by developer trunk or how to start by developer trunk

Tags: lucene, solr

I have downloaded solr from :

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/

and when i try to start solr by :

```
/solr/example/java -jar start.jar &
```

and try to open in browser at 8983 port it is not opening saying ?

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /solr/admin/schema.jsp. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND

Powered by Jetty://
```

how to start by developer trunk actually want to use solr 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have downloaded the source code from trunk, it does not come bundled with the solr.war.

Can execute `ant` command from the base directory OR

Build the artifacts for solr by executing `ant dist` from the solr folder

Once the artifacts is built, you will find a dist folder with the apache-solr-xx.war

You would need to copy the war (and rename to solr.war) into the /solr/example/webapps/ for solr to be available.

This should get you started.

Example steps -
1. svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/ solr_trunk
2. cd solr_trunk
3. ant or ant dist (from solr folder)
4. Copy the war file (and rename to solr.war) from solr/dist folder to /solr/example/webapps/
5. /solr/example/java -jar start.jar

Comment: apt-get install ant ant-optional for installing ant

Answer (score 0):

See the [README.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/README.txt):

> To compile the sources run 'ant compile'

This will compile you the `solr.war`.